# meaning of the "reads" keyword in terms of RNA-seq or next generation sequencing

Tags: bioinformatics, molecular-genetics, gene-expression, rna-sequencing

I'm an undergraduate student at computer science and currently, I'm interested in bioinformatics. Today, I've started to read a paper about clustering and classification of non-coding RNAs [can be found here](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/30/12/i274.long) and I've seen a word ***RNA-seq read***. Altough I searched a lot to learn about, I can not find the definition of it, the thingsI found was about performance issues of techniques rather than explanation of the word. So, is there anyone who can simply explain me what is the meaning of this word as well as RNA-seq technique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RNA sequencing, the RNA is fragmented, DNA is synthesized complementary to the RNA fragments, which is  followed by a complementary strand synthesis. Fragmentation can be done after the cDNA synthesis too.
This DNA is then amplified to form a cluster that is sequenced. Most Next-Gen sequencing approaches sequence a short segment of the DNA (it has improved with experimental and technical optimization).

A read refers to the sequence of a cluster that is obtained after the end of the sequencing process which is ultimately the sequence of a section of a unique fragment. If an RNA is expressed in high copies then there will be more reads coming from it; reads can be redundant as well.

---

[image]

[Courtesy](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Ezhangx39/PLNT7690/presentation/presentation.html)